# apply style on element 1 adjacent to element 2 if element 2 child is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

how can i achieve this ?

```js
 const element = () => {

   return <div>
     <Container1 />
     <Container2 />
  </div>
}

 const Container1 = () => {
   return  <div className="container-1"></div>
}

 const Container2 = () => {
   const [preview,setPreview] = useState(true)

   return 
     <div className="container-2">
       {preview ? <div className="preview"></div> : ""}
  </div>
}
```

so what i want is that if preview is shown then apply style on container-1 and if it's achievable with css

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be

```html
<div className={preview ? "container-1" : ""}></div>
```

Comment: sry i haven't explained myself well, i edited for better example

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Element = () => {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={`container-1 ${preview ? 'container-1-preview-shown' : ''}`}></div>
      <div className="container-2">
        {preview ? <div className="preview"></div> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Element;
```

```css
.container-1-preview-shown {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: sry i haven't explained myself well, i edited for better example